# Mathematical proof or any reference of "Deterministic random bit generator cannot produce more randomness than the randomness of seed"

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator, dual-ec-drbg

The heading tells everything. Any proof or any kind of reference is welcome regarding this:

Can we get more randomness from a deterministic random bit generator than the entropy that we feed to the generator?

Comment: The correctness of the assertion obviously pivots around how _"more randomness"_ is defined. In the framework of [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity), and when we consider the DRBG public, we can describe the output sequence of the DRBG as: DRBG(seed), thus the increase in complexity (if any) is minimal and asymptotically negligible [with correction, thanks to @Patriot]. This is not an answer, since that's neither a reference nor a true proof, even in one framework.

Answer (score 6):

Define the [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) of a pair of random variables.
$$I(X; Y) = H(X) - H(X\mid Y)$$
For discrete random variables we hae that $H(X\mid X) = 0$, so:
$$I(X; X) = H(X)$$

The [Data-Procesing Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_processing_inequality) states that for *any* function $f$, we have that:
$$I(f(X); f(Y)) \leq I(X; Y)$$
While we won't need it here, this includes randomized functions, provided they use randomness independent of either $X$ or $Y$.
Combining these two, we get that:

$$H(f(X)) - H(f(X)\mid f(X)) \leq H(X) - H(X\mid X)$$
If $f$ is deterministic, I believe the conditional entropies become 0, giving us:
$$H(f(X)) \leq H(X)$$
So the output distribution of a DRBG is always lower entropy than the distribution that its seed is drawn from.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks a lot sir. @Mark